# GIT Change Submodule URL in Post-update script

Tags: git, git-submodules

How can I change the URLs of submodules during post-update to point to a new URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know about (besides tweaking git config) is running

```
git remote set-url <url>
```

in each submodule's directory.